# Rails, how to specify which fields to output in a controller's JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

in my controller I currently have:

```
invite = Invite.find_by_token(params[:id])
user = invite.user

json_response({
  user: user
})

def json_response(object, status = :ok)
  render json: object, status: status
end
```

Right now, user is returning all user fields. I want to return just (id, email)... I've tried:

```
user = invite.user.select(:id, :email)
user = invite.user.pluck(:id, :email)
```

neither works. Ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is an accurate representation of your issue. `render json: {user: user.pluck(:id, :email), status: status}` will **not** return the whole serialized user object. If you have simplified the problem in an attempt to provide a minimal scenario, can you please ensure it's still a verifiable description?

Comment: @TomLord your suggestion results in an error `undefined method `pluck' for #<User`

Comment: Ah right sorry, I forgot we were dealing with a single object here .... So you *could* have done `user.attributes.extract!('id', 'name')`. Using `as_json` is better though. My point, basically, was that **your question did not describe your error**.

Comment: @TomLord sorry about that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [as_json](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) passing attributes you want in the response, like:

`user.as_json(only: [:id, :email])`

Answer (score 4):

I know this question already has an answer, but there is also a nice gem you could use called [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable). This lets you specify exactly which properties you want in your JSON output for different models and even let's you include relationships to other models in your response.

Gemfile:

`gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'`

Then run `bundle install`.

You can then create a serializer using the generator command:

`rails g serializer user`

which will create the serializer in `project-root/app/serializers/`.

In your serializer, you can whitelist the attributes you would like:

**project-root/app/serializers/user_serializer.rb**:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email
end
```

Now any time you return a `User` object it will only output those two attributes, `id` and `email`.

Want to print out related models? Easy. You can just add the relationship in your serializer and it will include those related models in your JSON output.

Pretend a user "has many" posts:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email

  has_many :posts
end
```

Now your JSON outputs should look something like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "posts": [{
    id: 1,
    title: "My First Post",
    body: "This is the post body.",
    created_at: "2017-05-18T20:03:14.955Z",
    updated_at: "2017-05-18T20:03:14.955Z"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "My Second Post",
    body: "This is the post body again.",
    created_at: "2017-05-19T20:03:14.955Z",
    updated_at: "2017-05-19T20:03:14.955Z"
  }, 
  ...
  ]
}
```

Pretty neat and convenient. And if you want to limit the the posts to only print certain columns as well, all you need to do is create a serializer for `posts`, specify the attributes, and the output will just work.